# Is there any inbuilt function to insert values in db used in Joomla framework?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Is there any inbuilt function to insert values in db used in Joomla framework?

I am looking for the insert query in adminitrator folder for #__menu table and other tables, but i can only find the update select and delete queries on searching in Dreamweaver, So please tell me is there any inbuilt function that Joomla uses for insert query? If yes, where is it located in Administrator codes file? and whats that function is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JDatabase](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Database/JDatabase.html) is probably what you need.

Have a look to the `insertObject` method.